# how to prove limit exists or not?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having hard time understanding what is the correct way to prove whether the limit exists or not for two variable functions of those two functions.

I don't know how to solve the first limit.
In the second limit I've tried to use $$x=r\cos \theta, \ y=r\sin \theta$$
but it didn't help me. I tried to use Squeeze theorem and got stuck.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^n+y^n)}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2\cdot y^5}{x^{3}+y^{9}}$$

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the comment. what should I add/edit in the post?

Comment: You could edit your post, adding to it what you have done thus far.

Comment: Ok, thank you- edited.